# ASP.NET No mapping exists from object type XXX.Models.AccountRole to a known managed provider native type, one to many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to register an user and he have a default attributes "`Role`", set at "`USER`". This attribute provides from a related table '`AccountRole`' but I've this error :

> No mapping exists from object type XXX.Models.AccountRole to a known managed provider native type.

I tried this :

**DbEntities.cs**

```
public class DbEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountRole.cs**

```
[Table("AccountRole")]
public class AccountRole
{
    public AccountRole()
    {
        Users = new List<UserProfile>();
    }
    //[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountRoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountRoleLabel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**UserProfile**

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile() {

    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountRole Role { get; set; } 

}
```

**RegisterModel**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
```

**EDIT**

```
    public RegisterModel()
    {
        DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
        AccountRole accountrole = db.AccountRoles.Find(1);
        AccountRole Role = new AccountRole();
        this.Role = accountrole;
    }
```

**FIN EDIT**

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nom d'utilisateur")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "La chaîne {0} doit comporter au moins {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmer le mot de passe ")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe et le mot de passe de confirmation ne correspondent pas.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Nom complet ")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public AccountRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountController**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Tentative d'inscription de l'utilisateur
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Name = model.Name, Role = model.Role }, false);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // Si nous sommes arrivés là, quelque chose a échoué, réafficher le formulaire
        return View(model);
    }
```

> **Error** : No mapping exists from object type XXX.Models.AccountRole to a known managed provider native type.

**EDIT** : After reflexion, get Role in role table it's better than recreate new one. But I always the same error :

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AccountRole_9E84587E3FD1A8E8356A2B8C874378A4725E1429BA029DF56367134D7C318AF4 to a known managed provider native type.

It's happened when I try to register someone

Thank you ;)

Comment: Googling for *XXX models* probably won't help in this case... ;)

Comment: XXX represents my project's name ;) I don't use it to search answer of my problem ! Can you help me ?

Comment: Besides that I'm not sure to understand what this error. WebSecurity doesn't find my property's value "Role", is that ?

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy...

After lots of debugging I understand my mistake..

**AccountController**

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {

        DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
        AccountRole accountrole = db.AccountRoles.First(x => x.AccountRoleLabel=="USER");
        model.Role = accountrole;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Tentative d'inscription de l'utilisateur
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Name = model.Name, AccountRoleRefId = model.Role.AccountRoleId}, false);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // Si nous sommes arrivés là, quelque chose a échoué, réafficher le formulaire
        return View(model);
    }
```

**CORRECTION**

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Name = model.Name, AccountRoleRefId = model.Role.AccountRoleId}, false);
```

AND NOT THIS:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Name = model.Name, Role = model.Role}, false);
```

Normal, `Role`isn't the name of column, it's AccountRoleRefId
And, `model.Role` is an `AccountRole` not a `int`